# prints out wrongly,positions of characters mixed up, whats wrong,loop

Tags: c, loops, printf

Mycode prints many lines with 9 elements each. If the line (first element) starts with 'd', then do not print out the rest elements of the line. so if you try ls -l | mycode it will delete lines starting with 'd'. BUT for some reasons the elements move left by one if for example:

```
ls -l

drwxrwxrwx 2 alk lotus 35 Sep 23 19.00 directory1
-rwxrwxrwx 2 alk lotus 345 Sep 23 13.00 file1
drwxrwxrwx 3 alk lotus 245 Sep 23 19.20 directory2
drwxrwxrwx 24 alk lotus 15 Sep 23 12.00 directory3
-rwxrwxrwx 5 alk lotus 25 Sep 23 14.00 file2
-rwxrwxrwx 8 alk lotus 25 Sep 23 10.00 file3

ls -l | mycode

-rwxrwxrwx 2 alk lotus 345 Sep 23 13.00 
file1 -rwxrwxrwx 5 alk lotus 25 Sep 
23 14.00 file2 -rwxrwxrwx 8 alk lotus 25 Sep 
23 10.00 file3
```

So why file2 file1 goes down? I wanna that file to stay in his place....After that all positions are mixed up there....Help please to fix this...
my code here:

Comment: What's the point of the fgets in the else block?

Comment: Alternatively, what's the point of using scanf?

Comment: Do not destroy a question after you have gotten answers.

Answer (score 1):

The logic in your code seems not correct. What you want to do is to remove lines that starts with `d`, however in the code you it does something else.

I'm presenting you an example which is expected to work, which shall replace your code example:

```
while (fgets(string, 1024, stdin))
    if (string[0] != 'd')
        printf("%s", string); // don't use puts cuz fgets would store the newline
```

Comment: well, it is still there, however the first line which has to be deleted is still there without first element starting by 'd' @starrify

Comment: @user2785535 What first line? Do you mean the `total XXXX` one?

Comment: after the total XXXX. It is a line starting 'd'. So the first element of that line is deleted and the rest of the line is still printed

Comment: @user2785535 It shall not be. And of course I cant reproduce the results you describe. Shoe me the full code that could reproduce your problem.

Comment: Maybe there is a bug... Ill try to find by myself. Anyway thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you aren't just using only fgets:

```
for (i=0; i<9;i++){
    if (NULL != fgets(string,1024,stdin)) {
        if (string[0] != 'd'){
            printf("%s\n", string);
        }
    }
    else break;
}
```